# Python: How to find if a path exists between 2 nodes in a graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I am using networkx package of Python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G=nx.empty_graph()
>>> G.add_edge(1,2)
>>> G.add_edge(2,3)
>>> G.add_edge(4,5)
>>> nx.path.bidirectional_dijkstra(G,1,2)
(1, [1, 2])
>>> nx.path.bidirectional_dijkstra(G,1,3)
(2, [1, 2, 3])
>>> nx.path.bidirectional_dijkstra(G,1,4)
False
>>> nx.path.bidirectional_dijkstra(G,1,5)
False
>>>
```

You can also use the result as a boolean value

```
>>> if nx.path.bidirectional_dijkstra(G,1,2): print "path exists"
... 
path exists
>>> if nx.path.bidirectional_dijkstra(G,1,4): print "path exists"
... 
>>>
```

Answer (score 29):

To check whether there is a path between two nodes in a graph -

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_edge(1,2)
>>> G.add_edge(2,3)
>>> nx.has_path(G,1,3)
True
>>> G.add_edge(4,5)
>>> nx.has_path(G,1,5)
False
```

For more information, please refer [has_path — NetworkX 1.7 documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.has_path.html)

Answer (score 10):

Using a disjoint set data structure:

Create a singleton set for every vertex in the graph, then union the sets containing each of the pair of vertices for every edge in the graph.

Finally, you know a path exists between two vertices if they are in the same set.

See the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) page on the disjoint set data structure.

This is much more efficient than using a path finding algorithm.

Comment: Well, I just implemented it for myself recently, and it works. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
shortest_path(G, source, target)
```

or one of the Shortest Path methods.  Stay clear of the methods which return paths between all nodes however if you merely have two specific nodes to test for connectivity.

Answer (score 4):

- [`dijkstra_path(G, source, target)`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path.html)

  > Returns the shortest path from source to target in a weighted graph G.

Comment: What if path does not exist between 2 given nodes? What does the function return then?

Comment: I don't want to find the shortest path. I just want to know if a path exists between 2 given nodes.