# Python Dictionary recursive searching

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

The way it works is that the keys can turn into any value from the lists they're associated with. So the question I'm trying to answer is can maximus turn into bumble. The function should return True because maximus -> bee -> bumble.

My function so far works with the following logic:

```
for i in transformers[start]:
    if i in transformers values:
        if desired in transformers[start]:
            return True
        else:
            return search(transformers, i,desired)
```

So what happens is it goes through the first recursion and says "okay, maximus is now prime." but in the second recursion with prime being start, it returns form the function and doesn't even check what would happen if maximus turned into bee, since once it hit OldPrime, it just returned with nothing.

```
transformers = {
    "maximus" : ["prime", "bee", "bomber"],
    "prime" : ["oldPrime","youngerPrime"],
    "bee" : ["bumble","oldBumble"],
    "plareon" : ["moltrees"]
}
```

Comment: Please post your function

Comment: Why would `maximus` be a `bumble` instead of `oldPrime`? Don't you want to exit because you found a match: `maximus -> prime -> oldPrime`?

Comment: @Bahrom: my understanding is that we look whether `maximus` *can* be transformed into a `bumble`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ahh I missed this bit: "_can maximus turn into bumble_"

Answer (score 4):

We can do this using recursion. Recursion always has base cases and inductive cases.

The base case is:

> "An object can transform into itself." (1)

The inductive case is:

> "An object can transform into the requested object `req` given it can transform into a next object `nxt` and that object can transform into the requested object. (2)

You can do this through recursion:

```
def can_transform(st, trans, req):
    if st == req:  # (1)
        return True
    else:  # (2)
        return any(can_transform(nxt, trans, req)
                   for nxt in trans.get(st, ()))
```

There is however a potential problem with the above approach: we can get stuck into an infinite loop. If for instance the transition dictionary looks like:

```
{
  'A': ['B','C'],
  'B': ['A']
}
```

and we look whether `'A'` can turn into a `'C'`, then the program will search the following path:

```
'A' -> 'B' -> 'A' -> 'B' -> ...
```

So we will never look for `'C'`.

We can prevent this from happening by maintaing a set of elements we already visited.

```
def can_transform(st, trans, req):
    visited = set()
    def recurse(st):
        if st == req:
            return True
        elif st not in visited:
            visited.add(st)
            return any(recurse(nxt)
                       for nxt in trans.get(st, ()))
        return False
    return recurse(st)
```

each time we thus visit an element, we mark it as visited, such that we can no longer visit it again.

Answer (score 2):

You should think of your problem as a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)). Now, to help you solve your problem.

If you don't want to create your own logic of finding if a path exists between two nodes in a graph you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620496/8833450).

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.DiGraph()

transformers = {
    "maximus" : ["prime", "bee", "bomber"],
    "prime" : ["oldPrime"],
    "bee" : ["bumble"],
    "plareon" : ["moltrees"]
}

# we create our graph here (from edges only)
for transformer in transformers:
    for form in transformer:
        G.add_edge(transformer, form)
```

Now, to see if we can transform from `form1` into `form2` we can just check:

```
if nx.has_path(G, form1, form2):
    print("Yay, we can transform!")
else:
    print("Oops! I cannot transform :(")
```

You should probably install `networkx` first. And now, here is your function:

```
def can_transform (transformer, form, transformers):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    for t in transformers:
        for f in t:
            G.add_edge(t, f)
    if nx.has_path(G, transformer, form):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**UPDATE**: Thanks to [Willem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) for hist comments that helped correct the answer.

Comment: Is this a *digraph*? Or just a graph. If it is an undericted graph, then the program will asume that if `maximus` can transform into a `prime`, then a `prime` can transform into `maximus` as well.

Comment: `>>> nx.has_path(G, 'prime', 'maximus')` returns `True`. Did +1, but you probably need to fix the fact that the graph is directed.