# Group elements based on condition in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of line segments, each with x and y coordinates of their "from" and "to" points, as seen below (example below is truncated, it's quite long).

```
[
{'f': {'x': 15.0, 'y': -5.0}, 't': {'x': 16.0, 'y': -5.0}},
{'f': {'x': 3.0, 'y': -7.0}, 't': {'x': 5.0, 'y': -7.0}},
{'f': {'x': 9.0, 'y': -7.0}, 't': {'x': 10.0, 'y': -7.0}},
{'f': {'x': 10.0, 'y': -4.0}, 't': {'x': 10.0, 'y': -5.0}},
{'f': {'x': 9.0, 'y': -4.0}, 't': {'x': 10.0, 'y': -4.0}},
{'f': {'x': 4.0, 'y': -4.0}, 't': {'x': 5.0, 'y': -4.0}},
...
]
```

I also have a function, `lines_connected`, which takes two of these list items (lines) as its `a` and `b` parameters, and returns `True` if the end of either line is on some part of the other (but `False` if they just intersect without one ending at the other, or if they don't "touch" at all). Using this, I need to find all groups (presumably as lists within a list) of lines which "connect" as described above. Not every line within a group is necessarily connected directly to every other line, but they are connected via other lines in the group.

What is the best way to group these lines into these "connected groups"?

Comment: This is a standard graph theory problem. Have you googled it?

Comment: This is a classic connected components problem. Each line is a node in a graph. Each connection between them is an edge. The connected components of this graph will be the groups of lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a graph problem. You can convert your list into a [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html) graph pretty easily, with your endpoints being the nodes and segments being edges:

```
import networkx as nx

def to_xy(p, key='f'):
    d = p[key]
    return (d['x'], d['y'])

segments = [...]
g = nx.Graph()
for seg in segments:
    g.add_edge(to_xy(seg, 'f'), to_xy(seg, 't'), obj=seg)
```

For reference, I've added an `obj` attribute to each edge, which points to the original dict used to construct it.

Now to get the groups, all you have to do is get the [connected components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html) of the graph: The edges within each component will be interconnected segments. These can be obtained according to the description of the deprecated [`connected_component_subgraphs`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_component_subgraphs.html) method:

```
components = map(g.subgraph, nx.connected_components(g))
edges = [list(nx.get_edge_attributes(sg, 'obj').values()) for sg in components]
```

To check if any two points are connected somehow, just check if there's a [path](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.has_path.html) from the starting point of one to the other, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2353768/2988730):

```
nx.has_path(g, to_xy(s1), to_xy(s2))
```

It does not matter if you use `f` or `t` for the endpoints.

Comment: Hi there! This looks good, but I'm getting a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'` error from it, for the line `g.add_edge(seg['f'], seg['t'], obj=seg)`. The points (`f` and `t`) are dictionaries with `x` and `y` keys. What's wrong here? I'm guessing it wants the `f` and `t` points in a different format/type?

Comment: @DodoDude700. I've added a function to extract the data more carefully. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Okay, this seems to have worked (though I have to use `nx.connected_components(g) instead of g.connected_components()`), but what I get out is groups of connected points, not groups of connected line segments. How could this be adapted to output lines instead?

Comment: I've updated with some code to get a list of lists of connected edges.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be to use a network based approach. You could use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) for this.

In this setup each line segment would be a node and the output of `lines_connected` will determine whether there is an edge between them or not. So, if `lines_connected` spits out True for any two segments `a` and `b` then you can create an edge between two nodes. Else you don't.

Finally you get the "connected groups" by using connected subcomponent graphs as in

```
import networkx as nx
#G would be your Node-Edge Graph created with line segments and the outuput of lines_connected 
sub_graphs = nx.connected_component_subgraphs(G)
```

Comment: I had originally thought of doing it this way, but it turns out to be unnecessarily complicated to compute the edges yourself up front. You're basically re-implementing parts of networkx at that point. Making the segments edges instead takes all the burden of computation away from you.